# What is the current highest rated chess engine?

Tags: engines, rating

http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/ - Indicates that it is Komodo 10 but I am not completely sure this is up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCRL has not tested Komodo 10.1 yet.

IPON has:  http://inwoba.de/

2016.07.23
Komodo 10.1 with a plus of 8 Elo in the full list and 11 Elo from one RRRL to the next.
This version would not be tested because it is to close to the last release but as it is the reigning world
champion it should be integrated.

1 Komodo 10.1    3253
   2 Stockfish 7   3228

Answer (score 3):

The CCRL maintains a [list](http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/) of chess engines and their ratings. Currently, Komodo (3358) is the strongest, closely followed by Stockfish (3340). According to the information on that page:

> Computed on July 23, 2016 with Bayeselo based on 642'252 games

it is quite up to date.

Comment: Komodo 10.1 came out on July 21st, so CCRL is behind.